# What is the difference between clearing the framebuffer using glClear and simply drawing a rectangle to clear the framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, 3d

I think at least some old graphics drivers used to crash if glClear wasn't used and that glClear is probably faster in a lot of cases but why? How are 3-d graphics drivers usually implemented such that these uses would have different results?

Comment: It could be faster because there is no need to go through the whole pipeline when using glClear. When drawing a quad, at least vertex shader, rasterizer and fragment shader have to be invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a high level, it can be faster because the OpenGL implementation knows ahead of time that the whole buffer needs to be set to the same color/value. The more you know about what exactly needs to be done, the more you can take advantage of possible accelerations.

Let's say setting a whole buffer to the same value is more efficient than setting the same pixels to variable values. With a `glClear()`, you know already that all pixels will have the same value. If you draw a screen sized quad with a fragment shader that emits a constant color, the driver would either have to recognize that situation by analyzing the shaders, or the system would have to compare the values coming out of the shader, to know that all pixels have the same value.

The reason why setting everything to the same value can be more efficient has to do with framebuffer compression and related technologies. GPUs often don't actually write each pixel out to the framebuffer, but use various kinds of compression schemes to reduce the memory bandwidth needed for framebuffer writes. If you imagine almost any kind of compression, all pixels having the same value is very favorable.

To give you some ideas about the published vendor specific technologies, here are a few sources. You can probably find more with a search.

- Article talking about new framebuffer compression method in relatively recent AMD cards: http://techreport.com/review/26997/amd-radeon-r9-285-graphics-card-reviewed/2.
- NVIDIA patent on zero bandwidth clears: http://www.google.com/patents/US8330766.
- Blurb on ARM web site about Mali framebuffer compression: http://www.arm.com/products/multimedia/mali-technologies/arm-frame-buffer-compression.php.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it faster? Because it is a function that bypasses most calculations that other types of drawings have to go through.

> Alpha function, blend function, logical operation, stenciling, texture mapping, and depth-buffering are ignored by glClear

[Source](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClear.xml)

Why do some drivers crash without it? It's hard to say, but it should have something to do with the implementation details of OpenGL. The functions does what it's supposed to do, but might do more that you don't know about. 
OpenGL might infer from this function call other tasks that it needs to perform.